# How to import JPA annotated class as persistence entity in Intellij 13

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I can create a new entity in persistence window of Intellij (TestE for example). It will create a class with JPA annotations for me. But I already have some annotated classes, how can I import them into the persistence tool window?

[image: Persistence tool window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I've find the answer.

I should add mapping class in `hibernate.cfg.xml`, like this:

`<mapping class="org.binwang.story.model.User"/>`